# Where can I get my torque wrench calibrated?

Tags: tools, torque

I have a couple of torque wrenches and a torque screwdriver that I've had for some years.  None has ever been recalibrated and although they haven't been abused and they seem to have good agreement among them, I read recently that one should check/recalibrate torque wrenches every couple of years.  These wrenches are fairly old (the youngest is at least 20 years old) and I'm not even sure I can locate the manuals for all of them.

My question is: Where would one go to get a torque wrench calibrated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any MAC or Snap-On truck/dealer has a universal *calibration* tool that will check the calibration.  The issue is that if they are "off", they will probably not have parts if needed, or perhaps the ability to adjust if the tool is not their brand or a similar popular style tool.

[AngleRepair](http://anglerepair.com/calibration/) will do it for $25 and some shipping if you can part with it for a while.  UPS it to them, they UPS it back with a sticker you can write on and impose your next scheduled cal date.  I'm not sponsoring them here; there are many others.  Google "torque wrench calibration service" and you will likely find an local industrial instrument shop that can do any number of recerts.

I'm such a SnapOn junkie, my dealer sends me Xmas cards.  I never have a problem finding him for recals.  And to be honest, I can't remember when an adjustment was needed... although I treat my tools pretty carefully. (Better than I treat my girlfriend!)

Answer (score -2):

I send my wrenches to Precision Cal Northwest(www.precisioncalnw.com). They're a calibration lab and a repair shop so they always have parts if needed. I'm a mechanic so I get my wrenches checked every 6 months just to make sure they're good to go. My wrenches do need adjustments about half the time but I use them often so thats to be expected. They also include what your readings are on your wrench so you know exactly how your wrench is performing.

Anyways they always seem to have good service and a quick turn around time. I've used AngleRepair in the past but I like this place better. They're easy to get ahold of and you can always talk to the technician that worked on your wrench if you have questions.